# Extra backslash in Sqoop import result

Tags: hive, sqoop

Currently i'm using Sqoop to import data from HP Vertica database to Hive, for some column with special character, the result is different from the data in the Vertica DB, here is the code:

```
sqoop import --driver com.vertica.jdbc.Driver --connect jdbc:vertica://db.foo.com/corp \
--username xx --P --where 'SRC_SYS_CD=xxx' --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' \
--m 1 --fields-terminated-by '\001' --hive-drop-import-delims --table addr             \
--target-dir /xxxx/addr
```

Data in vertica DB:

```
SRC_SYS_CD  CTRY_CD ADDR_ID ADDR_TYP_CD ADDR_STR_1_LG_NM
123456      NZ      107560  NULL        C\ - 108 Waiatarua Road
```

Data showed in Hive DB:

```
SRC_SYS_CD  CTRY_CD ADDR_ID ADDR_TYP_CD ADDR_STR_1_LG_NM
123456      NZ      107560  NULL        C\\ - 108 Waiatarua Road
```

The only difference is in column ADDR_STR_1_LG_NM, which after sqoop importing, one backslash(\) was added. While other column that does not have a backslash (\) was not changed.

Since there is NULL in vertica, we must use --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N'.

I've tried some other options like:

```
--escaped-by \\ --optionally-enclosed-by '\"'
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For DBs that sqoop supports direct connect, use **--direct** and remove **--hive-drop-import-delims** will import data as-is.

[This link lists DB that sqoop supported](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_supported_databases)

While i've confirmed Vertica is supported with direct connect but not listed.